# Why is there no heating at all until we use hot water?

Tags: plumbing, heating

My boyfriend has a combi boiler and he's very confused as to why he has no heating at all through the radiators until he uses hot water.

On the meter it says radiators shouldn't be working but they are. He has the council out but they just keep putting it off. Please can anyone help as it's winter soon and he will need them working without having to run hot water, for our baby's sake.

Answer (score 4):

Most water-coil heaters have a circulating pump to run hot water through radiator when the HVAC needs it.

It sounds to me like you either have no circulating pump, or that your circulating pump is malfunctioning.